# Syslog randomly logs bad time

Tags: syslog, time, date

Try as I might, I can't figure out why this server randomly timestamps syslog entries with bad time.

Here's a 5-minute stretch of syslog from a few minutes ago.  You'll notice there are two places where the time is logged wrong.  Once where it logs it as January 10th (off by ~4 days) and another where it logs it as November 16th (either ~2 months behind or ~10 months ahead--can't tell since syslog doesn't log the year):

```
Jan 14 18:25:01 tetrad CRON[15482]: (root) CMD (zfs-auto-snapshot -q -g --label=frequent --keep=12  //)
Jan 14 18:25:01 tetrad CRON[15483]: (root) CMD (if [ -x /etc/munin/plugins/apt_all ]; then munin-run apt_all update 7200 12 >/dev/null; elif [ -x /etc/munin/plugins/apt ]; then munin-run apt update 7200 12 >/dev/null; fi)
Jan 14 18:25:03 tetrad zfs-auto-snap: @zfs-auto-snap_frequent-2015-01-15-0225, 1 created, 1 destroyed, 0 warnings.
Jan 14 18:26:54 tetrad puppet-master[31196]: message repeated 2 times: [ Could not find default node or by name with 'kvm4.virt.pne.local, kvm4.virt.pne, kvm4.virt, kvm4' on node kvm4.virt.pne.local]
>> Jan 10 00:00:01 tetrad CRON[18094]: (root) CMD (if [ -x /etc/munin/plugins/apt_all ]; then munin-run apt_all update 7200 12 >/dev/null; elif [ -x /etc/munin/plugins/apt ]; then munin-run apt update 7200 12 >/dev/null; fi)
Jan 14 18:27:01 tetrad CRON[18094]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/bin/lockrun --lockfile=/root/updatecw.lock -- /root/sqlworkbench/updatecw.sh > /dev/null)
Jan 14 18:28:02 tetrad fetchmail[7149]: message repeated 51 times: [ Warning: the connection is insecure, continuing anyways. (Better use --sslcertck!)]
>> Nov 16 23:45:01 tetrad CRON[20554]: (root) CMD (if [ -x /etc/munin/plugins/apt_all ]; then munin-run apt_all update 7200 12 >/dev/null; elif [ -x /etc/munin/plugins/apt ]; then munin-run apt update 7200 12 >/dev/null; fi)
Jan 14 18:29:04 tetrad fetchmail[7149]: Warning: the connection is insecure, continuing anyways. (Better use --sslcertck!)
Jan 14 18:29:58 tetrad kernel: [7713426.484590] ip_set: protocol 6
```

I have verified the timezone settings are correct on the box, and I've completely stopped rsyslogd and started it again.  I can even leave a loop running on the box for hours without an error:

```
while true; do date; sleep 1; done
```

...so it doesn't appear to be an issue with the clock.  Reviewing 10,000+ lines of 'date' output in the console sucks!  ;)

I should point out that I've only ever seen it when logging a CRON action.  The cron jobs are not long running, and I've even tested by commenting out all the jobs in cron for a day.  No false time entries.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Very likely the same issue as http://serverfault.com/questions/636901/random-ssh-entries-in-auth-log-out-of-date-order/655076