# maillog files not in chronological date order

Tags: logging, log-files, centos7, rsyslog

I am running centos 7 LAMP server with webmin and recently disabled mailman from the bootup and shutdown module of webmin and then rebooted the system. I am positive my log files(such as maillog, cron, secure) were correct and in date order before i rebooted.

I then went to view my maillog after the reboot and found all the entries have been jumbled up like so :

> Nov 7
>   Nov 7
>   Nov 7
>   oct 12
>   oct 12
>   oct 12
>   nov 8 
>   nov 8 
>   nov 8 
>   nov 8 
>   nov 8 
>   Nov 7
>   Nov 7

This has also happened for other log files such as `secure` and `cron`.

I have tried Force Log Rotation which fails and produces no output for the fail.

I have also tried to restart mailman and reboot as well as restarting `rsyslog` service but the log files are still out of date order.

If my log files are out of chronological date order will this affect the general functioning of my server?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Since typically log messages get appended that is *odd* to say the least. What kind of server? Hardware, VPS, something else, what time source?

Comment: Could Craig Miskell's answer to http://serverfault.com/questions/608690/weird-syslog-order be relevant? Sounds like similar symptoms if the logging stack matches.

Comment: Thanks Paul for your link, it does seem to be the same problem however being on centos i couldn't find the RepeatedMsgReduction in my rsyslog config, so i added it to the config file which had no affect. So now i have reinstalled my whole system and tried to replicate the problem by doing the same steps as above but i can not replicate the problem. Its rather annoying i couldn't fix the problem just in case it happens again.